# InnerHTML solution needed - Should be easy to answer

Tags: javascript, variables, innerhtml

I am new to JavaScript so please be understanding of my situation.

I have created a simple HTML form which includes a drop down menu (to select quantity of item) and a submit button (to add to a cart).

Once submitted the results of the form are displayed in a table on the webpage.

So far with my code I can display the results of the form options.

However, I need to replace the quantity with the variable result for "qtytoy1".

Here is my code.

```
function addToy1New()
{
var i = document.getElementById("qty_toy1");
var qtytoy1 = i.options[i.selectedIndex].text;
var htmlTagString="<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\">"
                    +"  <tr>"
                    +"    <td>Optimus Prime</td>"
                    +"    <td> x 1</td>"
                    +"    <td>$26.99</td>"
                    +"  </tr>"

                    +"  <tr>"
                    +"    <td></td>"
                    +"    <td>Total:</td>"
                    +"    <td>$26.99</td>"
                    +"  </tr>"
                    +"</table>";

document.getElementById("toy1_add").innerHTML=htmlTagString;
document.getElementById("toy1_test").innerHTML=qtytoy1;
}
```

How can I replace "$26.99" with my variable "qtytoy1"?

I am pretty sure there are better ways around this method. Please share if you think so but make sure it is understandable for a novice such as myself. :)

Comment: I recommend using jQuery. It makes life a lot easier. http://jquery.com/

Comment: Please post your html, otherwise its impossible to answer without making assumptions.

Comment: `document.createElement` & `document.appendChild`?

Comment: Are you really asking how to insert a variable where it currently says "<td>$25.99</td>"? @d_inevitable jQuery won't help with the OP's question, will it?

Comment: @JuanMendes the op has asked for "better ways round it". So I've added a recommendation. In a comment, not an answer. Also when does jQuery ever solve a problem that can't be solved without it? Quite impossible, isn't it?

Comment: @d_inevitable: What I mean is, how would you use jQuery to solve the OP's problem with string concatenation? Maybe if you mentioned jQuery.template, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

Comment: @JuanMendes it was quite clear to me that he wanted to edit the variable `htmlTagString`, there was also the possibility that `#toy1_add` already had that kind of html and need only that one `td` replaced, in that case `jQuery` would be quite handy. But, yes jQuery template is also a good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var htmlTagString="<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\">"
                    +"  <tr>"
                    +"    <td>Optimus Prime</td>"
                    +"    <td> x 1</td>"
                    +"    <td>" + qtytoy1 + "</td>"
                    +"  </tr>"

                    +"  <tr>"
                    +"    <td></td>"
                    +"    <td>Total:</td>"
                    +"    <td>" + qtytoy1 + "</td>"
                    +"  </tr>"
                    +"</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. Worked this out before you posted but appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `replace` method on your string:

```
htmlTagString = htmlTagString.replace("$26.99", qtytoy1);
```

Then go on from there.

Comment: I dont think this answer deserves a downvote. The question is vague so people can only assume on what is meant by it. +1up to counter the downvote.

Comment: Agree, from the OP's perceived level of JS expertise, this answer does what was asked. It is just really inelegant.